# Can you change the starting directory of a select file dialog with a Google Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

When you click on a select file button on a website (`<input type="file">`) in Chrome, a file dialog opens, showing you a specific directory. This directory is the place of the last file you selected with such a button, even if it was on a different website or if you restarted Chrome. That means that there is some variable within Chrome that saves the starting folder of the next select file dialog.

Is there a way to change this starting folder using a Chrome extension/[Chrome API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index)?

Comment: No, there's no way.